# MATLAB - working with timestamps

Tags: matlab, timestamp

How can I convert this kind of data 08:00:43.771 given as string into a number specifying the number of milliseconds since midnight corresponding to this time instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I generally use the Matlab datenum outputs for timestamping in Matlab.  Datenums are the number of days since 0/0/0000, expressed as a double (double precision numbers are precise to about 14 usec for contemporary dates).

Using datenums.

```
 currentDateTime1 = datenum('08:00:43.771');           %Assumes today 
 currentDateTime2 = datenum('6/8/1975 08:00:43.771');  %Using an explicit date

 millisecondsSinceMidnight = mod(currentDateTime1 ,1) *24*60*60*1000;  %Mod 1 removes any day component
 millisecondsSinceMidnight = mod(currentDateTime2 ,1) *24*60*60*1000;  %Then this is just a unit conversion
```

For unusual string formats, use the extended form of `datenum`, which can accept a string format specifier.

Answer (score 0):

Use `1000*etime(datevec('08:00:43.771'),datevec('0:00'))` to give the number of milliseconds since midnight. `etime` gives the number of seconds between two date vectors, `datevec` converts strings to date vectors (assuming Jan 1 this year if only a time is given).